# Where is the RAID volume under Linux when configuring onboard Supermicro X10SRi-F

Tags: linux, raid, supermicro

I have a Supermicro SYS-5018R-MR with a X10SRi-F mainboard. I've configured the onboard RAID adapter ([via CTRL+I during boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNpmn.png)) to use two drives in bays 4 and 5 for a RAID1 configuration. The volume is reported as "normal" and the volume (I've named it ssd_vol) does appear in the BIOS boot config as a boot option.

When I boot into Ubuntu 14.04 however, I see only the [two individual RAID member drives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3cMi.png) and my USB boot drive. There is no device entry for `ssd_vol` or any additional device suggesting a RAID device.

I've looked over the user manual an the only information is really just a cursory walk-thorough of the BIOS menu options.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That motherboard has 'fake-RAID' that requires a combination of BIOS/UEFI config *AND* OS drivers. It's based on Intel's C612 chipset which provides 'RSTe 4.0' RAID capabilities, so look on Supermicro and/or Intel's support/download site and download the RAID/RSTe drivers and you should be good - I know you version of Linux is supported anyway.

Comment: Ugh.. thanks. Any recommendations for a hardware RAID card for this 1U? I'd rather throw some money into it and forego the driver shenanigans.

Comment: Adaptec/Microsemi are great.

Comment: Why not use MDADM? Grub supports booting from a MDADM RAID1.